# When and why did baseball players start exclusively running the bases counterclockwise?

Tags: rules, baseball, history

In modern baseball, the players always run around the bases counterclockwise (anticlockwise).  However, a book written in the 1830's - one of the first to describe the version of the sport we know today - which lays out the rules of the game, says that at that time, players would run around the bases clockwise (*The Book of Sports*, Robin Carver, 1834).

When and why did baseball players begin to run the bases solely in a counterclockwise direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**When?** This evolved over time to what we know in modern baseball today. The first known time the players were instructed to run counterclockwise was in 1839 ([page 40](https://books.google.com/books?id=gUNXAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&dq=it+is+here+The+Book+of+Sports,+Robin+Carver&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjljabXjuvLAhVMFx4KHROEDC0Q6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=it%20is%20here%20The%20Book%20of%20Sports%2C%20Robin%20Carver&f=false), *Early Professional Baseball and the Sporting Press*, R. Terry Furst, 2014).

One mandate regarding running counterclockwise in the MLB was made after Herman Schaefer stole first from second<sub>[(1)](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/08/there-once-was-a-major-league-baseball-player-who-stole-first-from-second/)</sub>. This is covered under Rule 5.09(b)(10) of the [2016 MLB Rule Book](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf).

> Any runner is out when:
>
> - After he has acquired legal possession of a base, he runs the bases in
>   reverse order for the purpose of confusing the defense or making a
>   travesty of the game. The umpire shall immediately call “Time” and
>   declare the runner out;

**Why?** [This article](http://research.sabr.org/journals/counterclockwise-sport) dives into factors that can be summarized by stating that the game of baseball developed into what it is today because the general population is predominately right-handed. This, as a result, influenced specializing skills such as switch hitting and left-handed batting rather than by default (ie, clockwise baserunning, a mirror image of what we know today).

A few quotes from said article:

> Clockwise baserunning, therefore, would necessitate that most fielders
> would have to turn before they threw the ball ...
> Since a majority of the population would find it easier to throw
> without first turning, and to swing the bat right-handed,
> counterclockwise baserunning gradually prevailed.
>
> Now the environment of the game can influence skills that can be
> learned. Professional baseball evolved with batters standing on either
> side of the pitcher-catcher axis. ... The
> left-handed batter stands closer to first base, and this provides his
> team with an offensive advantage. He can both reach first more
> quickly, and block the catcher's view of the runner on first.
>
> Baseball developed in a manner favoring the very specialized skill of
> right-handed throwing, and the less-specialized technique of
> left-handed hitting. Most ball-players at all positions throw
> right-handed; many bat left-handed, however, and there have been very
> few hitters indeed who bat right and throw left. Because of the
> necessity for speed in throwing, there have been no regular, longtime
> southpaws at C, 2B, SS, or 3B in this century.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning [Herman Schaefer](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/08/there-once-was-a-major-league-baseball-player-who-stole-first-from-second/), who once stole first from second base.

Comment: @chepner That's a good find. Although running counterclockwise became exclusive sometime in the mid-1800s, Schaefer was the reason a mandate to run counterclockwise was made.

Comment: I think everyone just *assumed* it was in the rule book up until that point; otherwise, you'd think someone hitting a slow dribbler up the first base line might try to run to 3rd instead.

Comment: When I was a kid, I read about Jimmy Piersall's backwards trot to celebrate his 100th career homerun. I always thought he ran clockwise, and they codified the counterclockwise rule at that time, but upon looking it up just now, I discovered (much to my disappointment) that he simply ran *facing* backwards.

Comment: @chepner In the modern day rule book, the definition of a run is "the score made by an offensive player who
advances from batter to runner and touches first, second, third and home
bases in that order." I wonder if that was in the rules back then (which would mandate running counterclockwise, but not mandate the stealing first from second scenario).